# INSERT dictionary sqlite3 (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlite

New to sqlite and having trouble with the syntax.

I need to iterate through each key of a dictionary and insert dict[key] into the column with the same name as the dictionary key. If it makes any difference, dict['Url'] contains the primary key, and all the rows are already created.

So far I think I've witnessed every possible OperationalError.

```
for key in merged_dict:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Games VALUES (?,?)", (key, merged_dict[key]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use named parameters for all your insert:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO GAMES (key1, key2, key3, key4) VALUES (:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4)",
            merged_dict)
```

This will take parameters by name from a dictionary, but those keys *do* have to exist. To support keys that may not exist (defaulting them to `NULL` instead, use a [`defaultdict` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) that will use `None` for missing keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

params = defaultdict(lambda: None, merged_dict)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO GAMES (key1, key2, key3, key4) VALUES (:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4)",
            params)
```

Comment: Thank you. Really thought there'd be an easier way to do stuff like this in py/sql...