# python sqlite insert libraries of varying size into table

Tags: python, sqlite

I'd like to insert the values of a Python dictionary into a SQLite table, where the key values are equal to existing SQLite column values.

```
in pseudocode: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table(library_keys) VALUES(library_values)")
```

I could not get it to work inserting library_keys and library_values as variables pointing to lists.  As I couldn't find any similar examples on-line I assume this is not possible.

I have found an answer that satisfies when the number of keys/columns is fixed: [stackoverflow: INSERT dictionary sqlite3 (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169122/insert-dictionary-sqlite3-python).
I have however libraries of varying size (up to 30 keys) which I'd like to INSERT INTO the table.  I could use IF ELIF to match the number of keys for each library to be inserted, but that would take 29 ELIF lines.
That somehow doesn't feel Zen.

Does anyone know a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a function for insert in python 3. I have tested it with 2 fields this can be extended to any number of fields. The table name is validated to protect sql injection security. Please check whether this works.

```
import sqlite3
def create_insert_string(table_name,input_dictionary,conn_db):
    #validate connection
    c = conn_db.cursor()
    #Check if the table is existing in the database if not throw error
    table_exist=c.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=\'table\' AND name=\''+table_name+'\'');
    if table_exist.fetchone()[0]==0:
        return 'Error'
    insert_str = 'INSERT INTO '+table_name+' ( '
    count=0;
    for keys in input_dictionary.keys():
        if count == 0:
           insert_str=insert_str+ ' '+keys
        else:
           insert_str=insert_str+ ', '+keys
        count=count+1
    count=0;
    insert_str=insert_str+' ) VALUES ( '        
    for keys in input_dictionary.keys():
        if count == 0:
           insert_str=insert_str+ ' :'+keys
        else:
           insert_str=insert_str+ ', :'+keys
        count=count+1
    insert_str=insert_str+' )'
    return insert_str
# Main Program
conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\PYTHON_SCRIPTS\\test.db')
dict={'column1':'value1','column2':'value2'}
insert_string=create_insert_string('test',dict,conn)
print(insert_string)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(insert_string,dict)
conn.commit()
c.close()
```

Comment: Hi Adithya, Great solution. I am not behind my desktop to test and implement it, but I am sure it will work just fine.